# Validation in Canjs

Tags: javascript, validation, canjs, canjs-plugin

How can I implement Canjs's validation? I'm having some trouble. On their guide page, they do it this way:

```
Contact = can.Observe({
init : function(){
    // validates that birthday is in the future
    this.validate("birthday",function(birthday){
        if(birthday > new Date){
            return "your birthday needs to be in the past"
        }
    })
}
},{});
```

But when I try this, I dont have any success.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. You just need to retrieve the validation errors using `.errors()` on your  observe instance ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daff/5DZAb/5/)):

```
var Contact = can.Observe({
init : function(){
    // validates that birthday is in the future
    this.validate("birthday",function(birthday){
        if(birthday > new Date){
            return "your birthday needs to be in the past"
        }
    })
}
},{});

var dave = new Contact({
    name: 'Dave',
    birthday: new Date(2024, 05, 05)
});

console.log(dave.errors());
```

You can find the full walkthrough in the [can.Map.validations documentation](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.validations.html).

Comment: See [can.Map](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.validations.html) in new versions of CanJS.

Comment: The fiddle no longer works... lots of broken links to CanJS external resources.